# Error : The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and am creating a question answer app

I am getting the following error:
`The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.`

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Log(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=False)
    created_by = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Log")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Logs")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"


class Solutions(models.Model):
    log = models.ForeignKey(
        Log, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    solution = models.TextField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Solution")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Solutions")

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.log.title} {self.solution} "


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    log = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"like by {self.user.username} for {self.log.title}"


class Comments(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    log = models.ForeignKey(
        Solutions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Comment")

        verbose_name_plural = ("Comments")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.comment}"
```

The error that I am getting is in getting the comments of a particular solution.

The function for that in views.py:

```
def solution(request, id, question):
    solution = Solutions.objects.filter(id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            solution = Solutions.objects.filter(id=id)
            com = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            c = Comments()
            c.comment = com
            c.created_by = request.user.username
            c.log = solution
            print(c)
            c.save()
            message = messages.add_message(request, 25,
                                       'Comment added successfully')

            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/solution/{id}/{solution.slug}')
        else:
            message = messages.add_message(request, 30,
                                       'Error')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        message = ''

    try:
        solution = Solutions.objects.filter(id=id)
        print(solution)
        comment = Comments.objects.filter(log=solution)

    except Solutions.DoesNotExist:
        comment = ''
        solution = ''


    context = {
        'comments': comment,
        'forms': form,
        'message': message,
        'solution': solution,
    }
    return render(request, 'solution.html', context=context)
```

The error is in the line `solution = Solutions.objects.filter(id=id)`

When I print the solution, it gives me a an empty query set.. Can anyone tell me the right way to do it?

I have a question (log as per in database) and solution to that question.. And the solutions have comments

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Solution.objects.filter(id=id)` returns a QuerySet and it could be emplty if the Solution with such id does not exist. In this case you cannot get an exception you want. Use `Solution.objects.get(id=id)`, then you will get a single instance or the `Solutions.DoesNotExist` exception.

BTW, `id` is a bad naming for variable in python, because `id` is a standard python function.

Comment: Ohk.. But I guess id is default name in django models

Comment: Yes, `id` as attribute for model is ok. But `id` as a variable for `def solution(request, id, question)` is not.

Comment: Ohk, I thought we have to pass the same name that we give in the urls.py

I have `path('add-solution/<int:id>/<slug:question>',
 views.add_solution, name='add_solution')` in the urls.py file.. So should it be changed in both places?

Comment: Yes, you should change it in both places

Answer (score 1):

```
solution = Solutions.objects.get(id=id)
```

`filter` returns a QuerySet while `get` returns an object.

Comment: That does not solve the issue.. Apparently what I am seeing is that, whenever I try to add a comment, it does not get added to the database and shows the error : `Solutions matching query does not exist.
`

Comment: That solves the problem. You just get another one. Now try and see why the solution does not exist.

Comment: I got the error.. There was no solution to add the comment to... So it was not able to add the comment.. Thanks